# Statistical Significance Test between mutually exclusive binary random variables

Tags: statistical-significance

I have 4 random variables that have binary outcomes, they are mutually exclusive. That means only one of them can be true at any given time. I have n repeated trials. How can I test the significance that any disparity between the frequencies / counts of each variable is not due to randomness?

**An example:**

- A survey with 4 choices (A,B,C,D)
- Every question ask which of A,B,C,D are the best for the given situation
- Determine whether the difference between A,B,C,D is statistically significant

Answer (score 0):

If you had six outcomes instead of four, this would be a lot like checking
to see if a die is fair. In R, `prop.test` is a way to see if the responses
are equally likely.

Fictitious data (fair die rolled 300 times):

```
set.seed(2021)
x = sample(1:6, 300, rep=T)
f = tabulate(x, nbins=6); f
[1] 56 46 56 50 46 46
```

Test for equally likely catigories. Unless the contrary is stated,
`prop.test` uses the null hypothesis that all categories are equally likely. [On account of moderately large samples, the continuity
correction is not used.]

```
prop.test(f, n=rep(300, 6), cor=F)

    6-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

    data:  f out of rep(300, 6)
    X-squared = 2.88, df = 5, p-value = 0.7185
    alternative hypothesis: two.sided
    sample estimates:
       prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4    prop 5    prop 6 
    0.1866667 0.1533333 0.1866667 0.1666667 0.1533333 0.1533333
```

Fictitious data (unfair die biased to favor `6`s over `1`s) and resulting test with small P-value rejecting $H_0:$

```
f2 = tabulate(x2, nbins=6)
set.seed(514)
x2 = sample(1:6, 300, rep=T, p = c(1,2,2,2,2,3)/12)
f2 = tabulate(x2, nbins=6);  f2
[1] 36 39 61 53 48 63

 prop.test(f2, n=rep(300, 6), cor=F)

    6-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  f2 out of rep(300, 6)
X-squared = 14.88, df = 5, p-value = 0.01089
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4    prop 5    prop 6 
0.1200000 0.1300000 0.2033333 0.1766667 0.1600000 0.2100000
```

It is important to have enough observations to give reasonable
power finding differences of the anticipated sizes.

Fictitious data with too few observations (only 60) to detect unfairness
of the prevailing level (P-value $0.8914 > 0.05 = 5\%):$

```
set.seed(521)
x3 = sample(1:6, 60, rep=T, p = c(1,2,2,2,2,3)/12)
f3 = tabulate(x3, nbins=6);  f3
[1]  8 10  8 12 11 11

prop.test(f3, n=rep(60, 6), cor=F)

        6-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  f3 out of rep(60, 6)
X-squared = 1.68, df = 5, p-value = 0.8914
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4    prop 5    prop 6 
0.1333333 0.1666667 0.1333333 0.2000000 0.1833333 0.1833333
```